# valuation of a particular element in $\Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider $x \in \Bbb{Z}_p$. Then I want to find the valuation of $(1+p)^x-1$. I think that $val_p((1+p)^x-1)=1+val_p(x)$. Is this right?

Actually I want to prove
that

$min\{val_p(1+p)^x-1, val_p(1+p)^{-x}-1\}=1+val_p(x)$

Comment: What is meant by $(1+p)^x$?

Comment: $x$ is the limit of natural numbers in the topology of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Then $(1+p)^x$ is the limit of $(1+p)^{th}$ power of those natural numbers.

Comment: Is it really an analogue of LTE?

Comment: @Leonetti: What is LTE?

Comment: It's still not clear how $(1+p)^x$ should be defined. For example, $\frac 14 \in \mathbb Z_3$, and by any normal definition $(1+3)^{1/4}$ should square to $2$, but $\mathbb Q_3$ does not contain a square root of $2$.

Comment: You can define them using binomial expansion. See for example the book 'p adic numbers ' by gouvea. Corollary 4.5.12

Comment: @Mathmo123, there’s really no problem, since athough $2$ has no square root in $\Bbb Z_3$, yet $-2$ does. Working $3$-adically, if you use the series, you find that $(1+3)^{1/2}=-2$, and similarly for $(1+3)^{1/4}$

Comment: @Lubin ah I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is greater than $2$ then your guess is true. Try to find a bound on the valuation of $n!$ and use the binomial expansion.

Comment: The failure for $p=2$ is very interesting, and repays closer examination.